# Custom Culture in SQL Server 2012+

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

In SQL Server 2012+, if I run the following:

```
select FORMAT(10.50, 'C', 'en-US')
```

I get $10.50 as expected. What I would like to do is be able to add or change the culture so that instead I get USD10.50 returned. Is that possible? Bonus points if it works in SQL Azure.

Comment: Why use a culture?  Why not just create the string the way you want it?

Comment: Because this function call or similar is used in 100 different places. To manually format it each time will be painful. Also because in production the culture will change for each user so it will get even more messy, I would need some kind of CASE culture = 'en-US' THEN 'USD' ELSE '£' END.

Comment: Although it does give me an idea of wrapping it in a UDF to replace the FORMAT.

Comment: Shouldn't this be done in the application and not in the database?

Comment: It is sometimes done in the app but for a lot of reports that is not really efficient.

Comment: If you're up for making custom formats, yes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/26etazsy.aspx#FormatProviders would be a reference.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
select Replace(FORMAT(10.50, 'C', 'en-US'), '$','USD')
```

OR a custom function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MoneyValue]
(
    @MoneyValue   money --or /int/decimal
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN
    RETURN Replace(FORMAT(10.50, 'C', 'en-US'), '$','USD')
END
```

You could put in a if then condition in your function for multiple currencies your dealing with. Don't know if this is outside the realm of what your asking.

If you want to build a custom culture:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.100).aspx